# Adding part of a stroke around a object after removed it (Toon Boom Harmony)

Tags: stroke

[image]

I want to add stroke again, I removed part of stroke, but I can't add it.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

*I am using Toon Boom Harmony v20.0.4*

You can recreate the stroke (pencil line) around an shape by:

1. Select the shape with the `select` [image: select tool icon]tool
2. `right mouse click` on the shape content
3. Navigating to the `Convert` → `Strokes to Pencil Lines` option.

`Shift+F12` is the keyboard shortcut for this command.

[image: strokes to pencil line command from right clicking the object]